# Create a Series using list comprehension and enumerate

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a df with some columns, such as:

```
for ind, name in enumerate(df):
    print(ind, name)

0 I_0
1 I_1
2 I_2
3 I_3
4 I_4
5 I_5
```

I would like to create a pd.Series using list comprehension. For example:

```
for (ind, column) in enumerate(df):
    dummy_I_q_ + str(ind) = df[column].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()

dummy_ind = pd.Series(dummy_I_+ str(ind) for i in range(len(samples_list)), index=temps))
```

But I'm getting a SyntaxError:

```
File "<ipython-input-29-3010489ec195>", line 2
    dummy_I_q_ + str(ind) = df[column].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

The expected output would be a pd.Series with values corresponding to columns of df, i.e.,

```
temps[0]  df[column[0]].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()
temps[1]  df[column[1]].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()
temps[2]  df[column[2]].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()
temps[3]  df[column[3]].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()
temps[4]  df[column[4]].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()
temps[5]  df[column[5]].iloc[100:140].nlargest(n = 10).mean()
```

How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: expected output?

Comment: addition for a variable name?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want to do, but you are effectively doing:

```
a + b = c
```

which Python does not allow, hence the error message.

I think this is helpful to the questioner, however you want to categorise it. And I cannot comment, duh.

Comment: Hey there, thx to helps but what you posted is a comment, not an answer. I advise you to remove this and make it a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**MCVE**

```
lst = list('zyxwvut')

pd.Series(*list(zip(*enumerate(lst)))[::-1])

0    z
1    y
2    x
3    w
4    v
5    u
6    t
dtype: object
```

---

Show that it works starting `enumerate` at a different integer

```
lst = list('zyxwvut')

pd.Series(*list(zip(*enumerate(lst, 5)))[::-1])

5     z
6     y
7     x
8     w
9     v
10    u
11    t
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I should get my lst values iterating over the columns in my df.

Comment: Honestly, idk!  If you post real data and how that translates into real expected output, I'd have a much better idea.  I answered the question by demonstrating what to do with a real data set.